# C# multithreading some threads seems to not run

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have an item processing application, and I want to process a number of items in parallel. But, it appears sometimes it doesn't process one item at all, and sometimes it processes more than once. My code below

On a timer tick, a new thread is created which prepares an item list from database, then locks every item so that it won't be picked in next loop.

```
SqlConnection connection = GetConnection();
string selectCommand = my_select_command_where_IsLocked_is_null;
List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>();
using(SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand, connection))
{
  using(SqlCommandBuilder cbCommandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter))
  {
    DataTable dtItemStore = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(dtItemStore);
    int totalRows = dtItemStore.Rows.Count;
    if(totalRows > 0)
    {
      adapter.UpdateCommand = cbCommandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
      foreach(DataRow row in dtItemStore.Rows)
      {
        Item pickedItem = new Item();
        pickedItem.Key = row["Key"].ToString();
        // Set all Item properties
        itemList.Add(pickedItem);
        row["IsLocked"] = 1;
      }
    }
    adapter.Update(dtItemStore);
  }
}
```

Then it iterates through the list, and fires a new thread for each element to process the item.

```
var keyList = "";
foreach(Item pickedItem in itemList)
{
  Thread.Sleep(15); // Just to delay a bit
  var newThread = new Thread(delegate() { ProcessItem(pickedItem); });
  newThread.Start();
  Logger.Log(" Spawn thread: " + pickedItem.Key + ", ThreadState: " + newThread.ThreadState);
  keyList = keyList + pickedItem.Key;
}
Logger.Log("Keys picked: " + keyList);
```

Item processor function unlocks the item at the end of the loop.

```
function ProcessItem(Item pickedItem)
{
  Logger.Log("Let's process !!! " + pickedItem.Key);
  // Item processing code

  UnlockItem(pickedItem); // unlock and write log
}
```

The problem is, after a while I realized there is too many locked items in my database, and the number is increasing. Logging at specific points I got something like below

```
- Spawn thread: 20779205, ThreadState: Running
- Let's process !!! 20779205
-  Spawn thread: 20779206, ThreadState: Running
- Let's process !!! 20779206
-  Spawn thread: 20779207, ThreadState: Running
- Let's process !!! 20779207
-  Spawn thread: 20779208, ThreadState: Running <---Not processed
- Let's process !!! 20779209                    <---Duplicate 
-  Spawn thread: 20779209, ThreadState: Running
- Let's process !!! 20779209
-  Spawn thread: 20779211, ThreadState: Running <---Not processed
- Let's process !!! 20779213
-  Spawn thread: 20779213, ThreadState: Running
- Let's process !!! 20779228
-  Spawn thread: 20779228, ThreadState: Running
- Let's process !!! 20779231                   
- Let's process !!! 20779231                    <---Duplicate
-  Spawn thread: 20779231, ThreadState: Running
-  Spawn thread: 20779237, ThreadState: Running
- Keys picked: 20779205, 20779206, 20779207, 20779208, 20779209, 20779211,   20779213, 20779228, 20779231, 20779237, 
- Let's process !!! 20779237
- STOP processing. Possible duplicate for 20779209
- STOP processing. Possible duplicate for 20779231
- Unlock Key: 20779209, Row count:1
- Unlock Key: 20779231, Row count:1
- Unlock Key: 20779209, Row count:1
- Unlock Key: 20779237, Row count:1
- Unlock Key: 20779228, Row count:1
- Unlock Key: 20779206, Row count:1
- Unlock Key: 20779207, Row count:1
- Unlock Key: 20779205, Row count:1
- Unlock Key: 20779231, Row count:1
```

Here I could see that sometimes the `ProcessItem` is not being hit (`20779208`, `20779211`). I couldn't understand why this could be... after spending two days on this, I am totally lost.

Is this something typical in multi-threaded environment? How can I better handle this? I have to make sure that every Item is processed once and only once.

Also, I realized sometimes same Item is being processed more than once (`20779209`, `20779231`), however, I handled it in the `ProcessItem` function to avoid duplication. Is there a link between those two scenarios ?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it possible that your timer is firing again after you have retrieved the items but before you have updated them to locked?

Have you confirmed that the field is being set to locked? What does SQL Profiler show as the order of queries on the DB?

Comment: @MattC, yes the timer may be firing, but I am using a field IsProcessRunning to skip the process in such cases... I will update my code. And yes the rows are locked. I will check the profiler...

Comment: You mark the iterator "row" (which you change inside the loop?!?!?!) as IsLocked, but where is your code that checks if a row is locked?

Comment: @PaulZahra , the checking is in my query `my_select_command_where_IsLocked_is_null`, it's something like "SELECT * FROM Items WHERE IsLocked IS NULL"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from output line `Keys picked: 20779205, 20779206, 20779207, 20779208, 20779209, 20779211,   20779213, 20779228, 20779231, 20779237` i would conclude that all items were hit (one time each)

may be you should modify your code to:

```
var keyList = "";
foreach(Item pickedItem in itemList)
{
  Thread.Sleep(15); // Just to delay a bit
  Item tmpItem = pickedItem; -- the same variable should not be accessed by many threads
  var newThread = new Thread(delegate() { ProcessItem(tmpItem); });
  newThread.Start();
  Logger.Log(" Spawn thread: " + pickedItem.Key + ", ThreadState: " + newThread.ThreadState);
  keyList = keyList + pickedItem.Key;
}
Logger.Log("Keys picked: " + keyList);
```

Comment: It looks like in C#5 the `foreach` was changed so declaring a local variable is no longer required: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Your log shows that `pickedItem` is assigned to the next value by the `foreach` loop before your `delegate() { ProcessItem(pickedItem); }` is executed.

You should use [ParametrizedStart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart(v=vs.110).aspx) instead or add a synchronisation system between `foreach` loop and `ProcessItem` function.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to spawn threads 'manually'?
Leave this task to the framework:

```
itemList.AsParallel().ForAll((item) =>
{
    Logger.Log("Processing item ...");
    ProcessItem(item);
});
```

Now all you have to do is make sure the `ProcessItem` method is thread safe.

### Edit

`ForAll` will block current thread until the action is completed for each item in the collection.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. didn't do much threading before... pretty much a learner. I will of course try this out.